# availableCameras is empty in IOS but no problem in Android

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

**In my code :**

```
final cameras = await availableCameras();
  // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
  final firstCamera = cameras.first;
```

**Package :**

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
```

> Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No element
>
> ## 0      List.first (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:220:5)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Can I use the camera please?</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Can I use the mic please?</string>
```

**Issue solved**
In IOS camera is not available in emulator

Comment: have you asked permission for camera in `info.plist` ?

Comment: @Sumeet.Jain  yes, i added it and updated it in my question

Answer (score 5):

The iOS Simulator doesn't have access to the camera. Trying to access it always results in a camera unavailable error. You'll notice that when trying to launch the camera app itself, you'll just get a static black screen with the UI but you can't take any pictures with it.